# CALayer: Maintaining cornerRadius on layer's contents

Tags: ios, calayer, cornerradius

I've been looking at the [CALayer's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and it seems like `cornerRadius` only affects the background of the layer and not the `contents`.

Is there a way to apply the corner radius to the entire `CALayer` without taking a big performance hit?

I've seen suggestions about masks, but that sounds costly. I've also seen suggestions about drawing the `contents` manually, but I don't really know where to start. I know a bit about rendering images in contexts, but I don't know how I'm supposed to draw it onto the `CALayer`'s content view with a corner radius. The best I would know is to subclass `CALayer` and override the `drawInContext` method and use `CGContextDrawImage`.

All help is greatly appreciated, but to reiterate the *question*: "Is there a way to apply the corner radius to the entire `CALayer` without taking a big performance hit?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cornerRadius` does apply to the entire CALayer and it does not cause a big performance hit. If you are not seeing the contents with rounded corners, it is because you have forgotten to set `masksToBounds` to YES.

Comment: Eesh. You're right. I guess I didn't do enough research. Thanks! Although, this has gotten me curious about drawing the CALayer's context for certain things.

Comment: Good! Drawing is easy and you should learn to use it with facility. My book teaches you how: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html. You can easily cause any drawing to be clipped through a rounded rectangle shape if that's what you want to do. But there's no need in this case.

Comment: Keep in mind maskToBounds will remove any shadow effect you have.

Comment: @kabram That's true, but the OP is worried about performance, in which case simple-minded shadows are ruled out anyway. If you want to show a shadow behind a rounded rect there are clever efficient ways of doing it, for instance as shown in my example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/ch22p667splitViewNoPopover/p560p575splitViewNoPopover/ShadowView.m